# Is there a way I can forward specific Webform Submission Results (from admin) to an email address I enter?

Tags: webforms, emails

I'm in the process of setting up a "system" where users can submit their Webforms with accompanying details/files and it gets logged into the Webform>Results>Submissions page.  This all works great.

What I'm having an issue with, is taking specific submissions from the full list and forwarding those select few to a specific email address that I indicate (somehow). This email address will vary.

The idea behind this is that sometimes I need another person(s) to look over specific submissions and instead of sending 1 at a time, I'd like to select a batch and forward them all at once from Admin.

I appreciate any insight into this issue!

Thanks so much :)

Comment: It seems like you need to write a custom form handler.

Comment: Did you try views with "send email" option?

Comment: I'm not super experienced with this so I'm attempting to use modules to do this - is "send email" a part of the Views module?